# How to use different set of resources (images, themes, etc.) during builds in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-resources

We need to build different looking apps for different clients from the same source base.  The app for each client has to be branded - i.e. must have different images, colors, etc.  Most of the resources - e.g. layouts, strings - will be shared among all clients.
We are thinking of using `sourceSet` in `build.gradle`. For example:

```
android {
...
    sourceSets {
        Main {
            // resources common to all clients
            resSrcDirs = 'res'
            // resources specific to client1
            resSrcDirs += 'client1/res' 
            // resources specific to client2
            //resSrcDirs += 'client2/res'
            ...

            // The same approach taken for manifest that contains application theme
            manifestSrcFile=client1/AndroidMainifest.xml
            // manifestSrcFile=client2/AndroidManifiest.xml
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Before each build we will uncomment/comment out selected lines in `build.gradle`.

We think that this would work but wonder if there is a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use flavorDimensions,

```
android {
    flavorDimensions "version"

    productFlavors {
        commom
        client1
        client2
    }
}
```

then create your resource folder src/client1 & src/client2.
In the Build Variants window,you can switch which style to run or debug.Refer to the figure below.
If you selected client1Debug or client1Release,the resources in client1/res will override the resources of the same names in the main/res.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is right, divide the source set per client brand.

We had the same experience and we resolved it like:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['jniLibs']
    }

    brandA {
        java.srcDirs = ['src_a']
        res.srcDirs = ['res_a']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets_a']
    }

    brandB {
        java.srcDirs = ['src_b']
        res.srcDirs = ['res_b']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets_b']
    }

    brandC {
        java.srcDirs = ['src_c']
        res.srcDirs = ['res_c']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets_c']
    }
}
```